# Cannot call `.is_valid()` as no `data=` keyword argument was passed when instantiating the serializer instance

Tags: django

I am really stuck overwhat is going on. Basically, i want to let the user change his phone number. He have to input just his current password and a new phone number. I want to pass the user to the init function so his current password can be validated along the way. But it gives me the above error message.

My serializers.py is:

```
class ChangePhoneSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
'''
Change my phone number
'''
password_current=serializers.CharField(max_length=16,allow_blank=False,required=True)
new_phone=serializers.CharField(max_length=13,required=True,allow_blank=False)

def __init__(self,*args,**kwargs):
    self.user=kwargs.pop('user')


def validate(self,data):
    phone=data['new_phone']
    pwd_current=data['password_current']

    errmsg=''
    if not pwd_current:
        errmsg=str(_('Current password must be given'))
    else:
        if not self.user.check_password(pwd_current):
            errmsg=_('Current password is incorrect')


    if errmsg:
        raise serializers.ValidationError(errmsg)

    return data
```

In my views.py:

```
    data=request.data
    serializer=ChangePhoneSerializer(user=request.user,data=data)
    if serializer.is_valid():
      #do stuff to change the phone
```

But it gives me hte above error. It was working fine when I wasn't use serializers.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're missing a call to `super()` in your `__init__()` method:

```
def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    self.user = kwargs.pop('user')
    super(ChangePhoneSerializer, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
```

Comment: Thanks! I completely forgot that